# iOS - Tableview rendering

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I'm pretty newbie in iOS app development so pardon me if my question is banal
I'm developing by using this environment:

- iOS 9.1
- xCode 7.1
- swift 2.1

I have this scenario:

- a MqttMessage is received by my app
- a local notification is generated
- the user see the notification detail
- then user can go to the messages list section or to the search messages section

I'm using all modal segues; now the problem I'm facing is that when from the notification detail i pass to the list messages section, the view is desplayed like if it was a full page 
How can I solve the problem?
This is how the list messages view is loaded as default:
[image]

And this is the rendering result when i come back from the detail notification by perform a modal segue
[image]

As you can see in the second image the list covers the upside section of the simulator (the part with times and network information -the carrier side)

What I'd love to obtain is that when i come back from the notification detail i'll always see the list messages as in the first images

Any tips would be great

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the notification detail you need to call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` rather than performing another segue. Performing will instantiate a new instance of your list view controller, one that not embedded in a navigation controller, thus why it takes over the entire screen.

Comment: thank you... I was sure it was something related to my code; it worked. I accepted the answer